# classic asp if statement issue

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a if statement which I am pretty sure it is correct and should work. But for some reason it is not.

```
while not oRs2.EOF
if iCat = oRs2("id")  then
%>
   <div class ="<%= oRs2("id") %><%= iCat  %>">
<%
else
%>
   <div class ="faqquestion <%= oRs2("id") %><%= iCat  %>">
<%
end if
%>
```

And this is what you get.

```
<div class="faqquestion 11">
<div class="faqquestion 21">
<div class="faqquestion 31">
```

but what it should be

```
<div class="11">
<div class="faqquestion 21">
<div class="faqquestion 31">
```

cant see what i am doing wrong, 1 does = 1!?

how the variables are being set:

```
dim iCat
iCat = request.QueryString("cat")

dim sSQL
sSQL = "Select * from table"        
set oRs2 = oConn.Execute(sSQL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is one of data typing.

For example I tested the following script (just take the contents and put into a file called test.vbs, then double click on it:

```
dim i
i = "1"

dim j
j=1

if i = j then
    msgbox "yes"
else
    msgbox "no"
end if
msgbox i & j
```

This will output "no" and "11".

In your code the iCat will be a string as you're just pulling it from `request.QueryString` so try converting it to an integer using `CInt`

Comment: iCat is always 1 and ors2('id') also contains 1 first time through loop

Comment: Ah - I see. Does it work if you make the if statement trivial? eg `if 1=1`

Comment: Updated with answer following extra info